# The Scala equivalent of PHP's isset()

Tags: scala, playframework

How do I test and see if a variable is set in Scala. In PHP you would use isset()

I am looking for a way to see if a key is set in an array.

Answer (score 6):

PHP and Scala are so different that there is no direct equivalent. First of all Scala promotes immutable variables (`final` in Java world) so typically we strive for variables that are always set.

You can check for `null`:

```
var person: Person = null
//...
if(person == null) {//not set
  //...
}
person = new Person()
if(person == null) {//set
  //...
}
```

But it is a poor practice. The most idiomatic way would be to use [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html):

```
var person: Option[Person] = None
//...
if(person.isDefined) {//not set
  //...
}
person = Some(new Person())
if(person.isDefined) {//set
  //...
}
```

Again, using `isDefined` isn't the most idiomatic ways. Consider `map` and pattern matching.

Comment: How do I do "map" and pattern matching?

Comment: @user1435853: see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html and http://dibblego.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Comment: The type would be written `Option[Person]` (square brackets), not `Option(Person)`.

Comment: @Madoc: of course, thanks! Remember you are free to edit/suggest edit of any post on SO.

Answer (score 6):

First, `Array` in Scala does not have keys. They have indices, and all indices have values in them. See the edit below about how those values might be initialized, though.

You probably mean `Map`, which has keys. You can check whether a key is present (and, therefore, a value) by using `isDefinedAt` or `contains`:

```
map isDefinedAt key
map contains key
```

There's no practical difference between the two. Now, you see in the edit that Scala favors the use of `Option`, and there's just such a method when dealing with maps. If you do this:

```
map get key
```

You'll receive an `Option` back, which will be `None` if the key (and, therefore, the value) is not present.

**EDIT**

This is the original answer. I've noticed now that the question is not exactly about this.

As a practical matter, all fields on the JVM are pre-initialized by the JVM itself, which zeroes it. In practice, all reference fields end up pointing to `null`, booleans are initialized with `false` and all other primitives are initialized with their version of zero.

There's no such thing in Scala as an "undefined" field -- you cannot even write such a thing. You can write `var x: Type = _`, but that simply results in the JVM initialization value. You can use `null` to stand for uninitialized where it makes sense, but idiomatic Scala code tries to avoid doing so.

The usual way of indicating the possibility that a value is not present is using `Option`. If you have a value, then you get `Some(value)`. If you don't, you get `None`. See other Stack Overflow questions about various ways of using `Option`, since you don't use it like `variable.isDefined` in idiomatic code either (though that works).

Finally, note that idiomatic Scala code don't use `var` much, preferring `val`. That means you won't set things, but, instead, produce a new copy of the thing with that value set to something else.